# alfresco how to get category name by javascript

Tags: alfresco

First I can get all sub categories by js,but I only get the category name like `English` etc.
I want to get category name like `/categories/General/Languages/English/American English` in js.Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my experiment, I found a better idea, the`categoryNode.displayPath` could get name like `/categories/General/Software Document Classification/Development Plans` directly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the path and replace the cm: and *x0020* with the appropriate characters.

A category is just a node, so when getting the path you'll get the following:

```
/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable/cm:Languages/cm:English/cm:American_x0020_English
```